# Collection <__NSSetM: 0x174a5c8f0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Exception was raised on sub-thread. It seems i do some UI task on sub-thread, but you can see i have called performSelectorOnMainThread from stacktrace, it confused me, can anyone help me, Thanks!

```
#14 Thread
NSGenericException: Collection <__NSSetM: 0x174a5c8f0> was mutated while being enumerated.
0 CoreFoundation    ___exceptionPreprocess + 124
1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 56
2 CoreFoundation    -[NSException name]
3 Foundation    -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:] + 388
4 Foundation    -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:] + 360
5 Foundation    -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 172
6 Foundation    -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 348
7 Foundation    -[NSISEngine optimize] + 112
8 Foundation    -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 112
9 UIKit -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 220
10 UIKit    -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1196
11 QuartzCore   -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12 QuartzCore   CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13 QuartzCore   CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
14 QuartzCore   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
15 QuartzCore   CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
16 QuartzCore   CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 660
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_tsd_cleanup + 572
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_exit + 200
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib  pthread_exit + 44
20 Foundation   -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
21 Foundation   ___NSThread__start__ + 1044
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_body + 240
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_body
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start + 4
```

Comment: `was mutated while being enumerated` This is not a error specific to background stuff. You can have in MainThread too.

Comment: add your code please

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of your crash? I have the same stack-track but no hint where it's coming from yet...